# Polymer -> Concept like WPF/SL DataContext in Bindings

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, datacontext

I want to use Bindings in Polymer Library also outside from Polymer COmponents (vie "dom-bind" of the content body of the Page). Now I have a question, is there a Concept like the "DataContext" of an Element as it is in WPF or SL in Polymer available? That means that I can define Bindings that are relative to a "DataContext" of the Element!

Example:

```
 <div id="droot">
   <my-conveyor isoccupied={{BB}}></my-conveyor>
 </div>
```

and I have a Javascript Object like this

```
{
    HH : {
        BB : true 
    }
}
```

and I set the DataContext of "droot" to "HH" so that is derived to "my-conveyor". Is something like this possible?
I need it, because we convert or WPF/SL Views automatically to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently, as far as I know, no way of doing this, but it could be possible to extend the existing [data binding helpers](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html) to support this features.
Something like:

```
<template is="dom-context" context="{{HH}}">
   <my-conveyor is-occupied="{{BB}}"></my-conveyor>
<template>
```

Comment: this is just an idea how it could work if such template was implemented based on templatizer. I'll try to do some experiment this week or next to try building such template! Other example of custom template: https://github.com/Trakkasure/dom-if-else/ or https://github.com/Trakkasure/dom-bindref/

Comment: Thanks, would be nice if you update me what you've find out!

Comment: For clarification: It would be nice if we have a DataContext wich is derived through the Dom, an can be used inside and outside of Polymer components for Binding (outside means in a "dom-bind" template). Inside a Polymer component we need to define a way that the datacontext should be used as Binding root, and not the component properties! For Example {{ $datacontext.property}}

Comment: Sure, come and join the Polymer slack and discuss with people with great expertise there!

Comment: I think I understood your need! :)

Comment: What's the  Polymer slack?

Comment: an official chat rooms where the polymer team interacts with the community, subscribe here: http://polymer-slack.herokuapp.com/

Comment: In knockout there is something like the one I want: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html